# How do I refer to localhost or my domain name in calls to files?

Tags: php, relative-path

I've been developing a website, but I develop on my local machine first.  I can access this with http://localhost/whatever through my browser, and the actual files are under /var/www/.  However, the file system on my web server is structured differently; my files are in the home folder.

I am also beginning to restructure such that I am putting modules in separate folders instead of everything being stuck in one directory.  I am therefore looking for a way to refer to my 'base' directory in each case.  Given that the structure might change in the future, I want a way to refer to files without having to change those calls after uploading to my live site.

Eg. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

If I call this from `includes/header.php`, and then I call `includes/header.php` from a number of different file locations, it tells me that it does not find `style.css` for obvious reasons: `style.css` is not in those folders!

In other words, the goal is some sort of relative pathing that is manageable between two places with different directory structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

should get the server root path, also below the 'www' folder

Comment: Thanks so much!  This works perfectly for my needs, regardless of the correctness of other responses.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that's sometimes used is to store the absolue URL of the root of your website to a variable, once :

```
$root = 'http://www.yoursite.com';
```

Two ways to get this :

- If you are deploying your application to a quite unusual location, you could set that in your configuration file
- Else, this can generally be determines from one of the items in `$_SERVER`.

Note: Instead of a variable, you might prefer using a constant.

And, then, in all `<link>`, `<script>`, ... tags, use that variable to have a correct absolute path :

```
<link href="<?php echo $root; ?>/css/style.css";
```

Of course, this means your `style.css` must remain in the `css` folder, always -- but it's probably going to be the case, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this post](http://islandlinux.org/howto/determining-application-root-php) is what you are looking for.